# Multiple rows in body of flutter application

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to create a screen in flutter that has 3 rows stacked on top of each other but I keep getting syntax errors. I have tried multiple containers in the body, Rows etc and keep getting syntax errors, is what im trying to do impossible? I would think Rows would be stackable, or at least containers in a body.

Here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Index extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF0099a9),
      ),
      body: Row(
        //ROW 1
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.orange,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
            child: FlutterLogo(
              size: 60.0,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
            child: FlutterLogo(
              size: 60.0,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.purple,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
            child: FlutterLogo(
              size: 60.0,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Row(
        //ROW 2
        children: [
          Container(
            color: Colors.orange,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
            child: FlutterLogo(
              size: 60.0,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

try to use the Formatter included by the IDE otherwise it will be a disaster to maintain the code.

https://flutter.io/formatting/

Here you have your code:

```
    class Index extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
            appBar: new AppBar(
              backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF0099a9),
            ),
            body: Column(children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                //ROW 1
                children: [
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.orange,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                    child: FlutterLogo(
                      size: 60.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                    child: FlutterLogo(
                      size: 60.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.purple,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                    child: FlutterLogo(
                      size: 60.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(//ROW 2
                  children: [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                  child: FlutterLogo(
                    size: 60.0,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                  child: FlutterLogo(
                    size: 60.0,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.purple,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                  child: FlutterLogo(
                    size: 60.0,
                  ),
                )
              ]),
              Row(// ROW 3
                  children: [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.orange,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                  child: FlutterLogo(
                    size: 60.0,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                  child: FlutterLogo(
                    size: 60.0,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  color: Colors.purple,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                  child: FlutterLogo(
                    size: 60.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
            ]));
      }
    }
```

Comment: thank u very much. I wasn't aware of a formatter, does VS Code have one? that's what i'm using.

Comment: I’m coming from the asp.net world trying to learn flutter , I love it so far but still struggle a bit

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Multiple Containers with Multiple Lines'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Wrap(
            spacing: 10.0, // Spacing between containers
            runSpacing: 10.0, // Spacing between lines
            children: [
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4, // Adjust width as needed
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Container 1',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                    Text(
                      'Line 1',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Line 2',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.4, // Adjust width as needed
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                color: Colors.green,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Container 2',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 18.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                    Text(
                      'Line 1',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Line 2',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              // Add more containers as needed
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> I used the Wrap Widget, I hope your problem will be solved!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).